# $\sum_{n=0}^{+\infty}\left(\frac{1-x}{1+x}\right)^n$ converges for some $x\in\mathbb{R}$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

For which values of $x\in\mathbb{R}$ does the series

$1 + \frac{1-x}{1+x} + (\frac{1-x}{1+x})^2 + (\frac{1-x}{1+x})^3 . . . . . .$

converge? What is it's sum?

My immediate thoughts were that all positive values of $x$ would produce a fraction smaller than $1$. In that case, all exponents of that fraction would be smaller than the original fraction.

I then realized that the odd powers would make the odd terms negative if $1-x$ is negative. I'm not sure that this would matter if the sum of terms in the series is supposed to converge.

Comment: Are you aware that $1 + r + r^2 + r^3 + \cdots$ converges if and only if $|r| < 1$?

Comment: My initial thought was that $x\in(0,1)$ would be convergent because each fraction would be smaller than the one before it (using ideas studies for sequences). But no, I have not seen that statement expressed for series.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since a series $\sum_{n=1}^\infty r^n$ converges if and only if $|r|<1$, your series converges if and only if $\left|\frac{1-x}{1+x}\right|<1$, which is equivalent to $x>0$.

Comment: Do you have any thoughts on its sum? Would the sum depend on the value of x?

Comment: @BobMcdonald Sure it does: as José says, at least when $x > 0$ you can use famous formula for the sum of a *geometric series* to find that the sum is $\frac{1}{1 - \frac{1 - x}{1 + x}} = \frac{1 + x}{2 x}$.